# How can I get data from 2 table based on specific condition

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL database, I have 3 table called **supplier**, **vehicle**, and **assigned** table.

**vehicle table:**

```
vid     vehicleName     noOfSeat     sid
========================================
13      x               10           28 
14      x               8            28
15      x               12           28
16      x               14           29 
17      x               4            29
18      x               8            30
```

**assigned table**

```
asgid   bid  sid  vid   did  seatBooked   assigned_start    assigned_end
============================================================================
56      15   28   13    17   3            06/01/2018 02:01  06/01/2018 04:02
57      15   28   14    15   2            06/01/2018 02:01  06/01/2018 04:02
58      15   28   15    16   3            06/01/2018 02:01  06/01/2018 04:02
```

In a reservation page, I need to assign a vehicle to a **selected date** which is **06/01/2018 02:01** To **06/01/2018 04:02**

Now I want to show **all vehicle** of a selected supplier as well as the **number of seat** from the `vehicle` table

But the condition is:

Those vehicles will be shown which has the number of seats available for my **selected date**: **6/01/2018 02:01** To **06/01/2018 04:02**

**For example:**

It's must be shown following vehicle with the number of seats:

```
vid    Mp pf Seat available
===========================
13     7 ( why 7? because on my selected date 3 seats booked)
14     6 ( why 6? because on my selected date 2 seats booked)
15     9 ( why 9? because on my selected date 3 seats booked)
16     14
17     4
18     8
```

*Its something like bus ticket system.*

## My Current Query:

Currently, I am using the following query but it just removes those vid which is in my selected date but it's incorrect because as you can see that on my selected date few seats are available!!!

```
// my selected date: From = '$timestart' and To = '$timeend'
foreach ($sid as $key => $value) {
    $vehicle->rowQuery("select * from vehicle where vid not in (
    select vid from assigned where assigned_start BETWEEN '$timestart' AND '$timeend' AND assigned_end BETWEEN '$timestart' AND '$timeend' ) AND sid = $value ");
}
```

I can't imagine how can I solve it: =(

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: My initial guess is that you are not actually storing your datetime values as datetime or timestamp... meaning you will need to do convert the values to filter them properly.

Comment: @Uueerdo do you mean I need to convert the date to `strtotime()` formate? If so then I can do it easily but the query :(

Comment: You should change the datatype in the table to `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: You'll need to use MySQL's [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert the field values to something that will work in the desired manner for the `BETWEEN` condition; and the `$timestart` and `timeend` should be be formatted in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format (or better yet, you should be using parameterized queries).

Comment: @Uueerdo I am changing the date to strtotime formate.

Comment: Also, I am guessing your BETWEENs need ORed, like `(a1 BETWEEN b AND c OR a2 BETWEEN b AND c)` ...and php's strtotime() is NOT going to help on values already in the database.

Comment: @Uueerdo I can change all date formate to strtotime() because there a few data like 5 data

Comment: Make sure to change the data type on the fields to DATETIME; you cannot expect string comparisons to behave appropriately for datetime values.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
select vehicle.*, (noOfSeat -  
  (select sum(seatBooked)
    from assigned
    where sid = 28
    and (assigned_start between '2018-01-06 02:01' and '2018-01-06 04:02' )
    and (assigned_end between '2018-01-06 02:01' and '2018-01-06 04:02')
  )) as seatsAvailable
from vehicle
having seatsAvailable > 0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6bcb6/15

Comment: Having issue. It's not sowing if I select different date. My main goal is not show available seat of my select date and the date from the assigned table. is it possible?

Comment: @Shibbir Didn't quite understand you, but this should work with any date, just make sure it's in the right format: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp)`